# Random Input From A List

Tags: python, random, input

I want to display a random input option for the user and if the condition is not met it picks another random input from the list.

```
import random

choice = ''
clues = []
clues.append(fname:= input('What is your first name? '))
clues.append(residence:= input('Where do you live? '))
clues.append(sname:= input('What is your surname? '))

while choice != 'smores':
    choice = random.choice(clues)
```

Doing this will just show each of the inputs then the choice is assigned a random answer from any of the inputs. What I want is for choice to pick sname as it's first option and if the user's response is not smores it will randomly pick another option from clues.

I used the walrus operator because I wasn't sure how I could save the input, using a normal variable just returns an error saying append does not take keyword arguments. The walrus operator still did what I wanted by storing and returning the values I need but if anyone has a suggestion on a different approach I'm all ears.

Comment: There isn't any point in the random selection if you're just going to loop till you get the one you want

Comment: Okay forget about the use case. If I want to just call random inputs how will I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this *might* be closer to what you're looking for. It will only show the first question, and then it will keep displaying a random question until you type "smores". It also saves all of the answers in a dictionary where the question is the key index

```py
import random

questions = [
    'What is your first name? ',
    'Where do you live? ',
    'What is your surname? '
]

answers = {}

question = questions[0]
answer = input(question)

while answer != 'smores':
    answers[question] = answer
    question = random.choice(questions)
    answer = input(question)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program already working you can use also this library in place of random.

```
import secrets
choice=""
clues = []
clues.append(fname:= input('What is your first name? '))
clues.append(residence:= input('Where do you live? '))
clues.append(sname:= input('What is your surname? '))

while choice != 'smores':
    choice = secrets.choice(clues)
print(choice)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it will ask for the input first. So in this case it will ask for the fname input, residence and sname respectively. After that it saves the input values to the them. So if fname is 'Sam', residence is 'house' and sname is 'Love', it will randomly pick one of them and assign to choice.

Comment: Also, if the input from the user does not match 'smores' it will cause an infinite loop of 'Sam', 'Love' and 'house' printing randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```py
import random

questions = ['What is your first name?', 'Where do you live?', 'What is your surname?']
choice = input(random.choice(questions))
while choice != 'smores':
    choice = input(random.choice(questions))
else:
    print('thank you for right answer!')
```